# Multiple Layouts in SwiftUI ScrollView overlap

Tags: swiftui, ios16, swiftui-layout

I've implemented a left aligned flow layout using the new iOS 16 `Layout` protocol, and I'm using it to add two lists of items to a `ScrollView` as follows:

```
let people = ["Albert", "Bernard", "Clarence", "Desmond", "Ethelbert", "Frederick", "Graeme", "Hortense", "Inigo"]
let places = ["Adelaide", "Birmingham", "Chester", "Dar es Salaam", "East Lothian"]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LeftAlignedFlowLayout {
                ForEach(people, id: \.self) { name in
                    NameView(name: name, colour: .red)
                }
            }
            LeftAlignedFlowLayout {
                ForEach(places, id: \.self) { name in
                    NameView(name: name, colour: .green)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct NameView: View {
    let name: String
    let colour: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .font(.body)
            .padding(.vertical, 6)
            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
            .background(Capsule().fill(colour))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}

struct LeftAlignedFlowLayout: Layout {
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let height = calculateRects(width: proposal.width ?? 0, subviews: subviews).last?.maxY ?? 0
        return CGSize(width: proposal.width ?? 0, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        
        calculateRects(width: bounds.width, subviews: subviews).enumerated().forEach { index, rect in
            let sizeProposal = ProposedViewSize(rect.size)
            subviews[index].place(at: rect.origin, proposal: sizeProposal)
        }
    }
    
    func calculateRects(width: CGFloat, subviews: Subviews) -> [CGRect] {
        
        var nextPosition = CGPoint.zero
        return subviews.indices.map { index in
            
            let size = subviews[index].sizeThatFits(.unspecified)
            
            var nextHSpacing: CGFloat = 0
            var previousVSpacing: CGFloat = 0
            
            if index > subviews.startIndex {
                let previousIndex = index.advanced(by: -1)
                previousVSpacing = subviews[previousIndex].spacing.distance(to: subviews[index].spacing, along: .vertical)
            }
            
            if index < subviews.endIndex.advanced(by: -1) {
                let nextIndex = index.advanced(by: 1)
                nextHSpacing = subviews[index].spacing.distance(to: subviews[nextIndex].spacing, along: .horizontal)
            }
            
            if nextPosition.x + nextHSpacing + size.width > width {
                nextPosition.x = 0
                nextPosition.y += size.height + previousVSpacing
            }
            
            let thisPosition = nextPosition
            print(thisPosition)
            nextPosition.x += nextHSpacing + size.width
            return CGRect(origin: thisPosition, size: size)
        }
    }
}
```

The `LeftAlignedFlowLayout` works as expected, returning the correct heights and positioning the subviews correctly, **but the two layouts are overlapping:**

[image]

I've tried embedding the two `LeftAlignedFlowLayout` in a `VStack`, with the same result.

If I add another View between the two layouts, e.g.

```
LeftAlignedFlowLayout {
...           
}
Text("Hello")
LeftAlignedFlowLayout {
...
}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

which seems to show that the correct size *is* being returned for the layout.

Any thoughts as to how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `calculateRects()` is always starting the layout at `CGPoint.zero` when it should be starting at `bounds.origin`.  Since `calculateRects()` doesn't have access to the `bounds`, pass the desired starting `origin` as an additional parameter to `calculateRects()`.  In `sizeThatFits()`, just pass `CGPoint.zero` as the `origin`, and in `placeSubviews()`, pass `bounds.origin` as the `origin`:

```
struct LeftAlignedFlowLayout: Layout {
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let height = calculateRects(origin: CGPoint.zero, width: proposal.width ?? 0, subviews: subviews).last?.maxY ?? 0
        return CGSize(width: proposal.width ?? 0, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        
        calculateRects(origin: bounds.origin, width: bounds.width, subviews: subviews).enumerated().forEach { index, rect in
            let sizeProposal = ProposedViewSize(rect.size)
            subviews[index].place(at: rect.origin, proposal: sizeProposal)
        }
    }
    
    func calculateRects(origin: CGPoint, width: CGFloat, subviews: Subviews) -> [CGRect] {
        
        var nextPosition = origin // was CGPoint.zero
        return subviews.indices.map { index in
            
            let size = subviews[index].sizeThatFits(.unspecified)
            
            var nextHSpacing: CGFloat = 0
            var previousVSpacing: CGFloat = 0
            
            if index > subviews.startIndex {
                let previousIndex = index.advanced(by: -1)
                previousVSpacing = subviews[previousIndex].spacing.distance(to: subviews[index].spacing, along: .vertical)
            }
            
            if index < subviews.endIndex.advanced(by: -1) {
                let nextIndex = index.advanced(by: 1)
                nextHSpacing = subviews[index].spacing.distance(to: subviews[nextIndex].spacing, along: .horizontal)
            }
            
            if nextPosition.x + nextHSpacing + size.width > width {
                nextPosition.x = 0
                nextPosition.y += size.height + previousVSpacing
            }
            
            let thisPosition = nextPosition
            print(thisPosition)
            nextPosition.x += nextHSpacing + size.width
            return CGRect(origin: thisPosition, size: size)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem solved. The issue was this:

```
var nextPosition = CGPoint.zero
```

when what it needs to be is:

```
var nextPosition = bounds.origin
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  I solved it by passing the `bounds.origin` to `caculateRects`: `func calculateRects(origin: CGPoint, width: CGFloat, subviews: Subviews) -> [CGRect] {`.  Since `bounds` is not in the scope of `calculateRects`, how did you get it there?

Comment: Exactly the same way you did; passing `origin: CGPoint` into `calculateRects`, with `.zero` in `sizeThatFits`. Great minds think alike! Thank you for your answer.